# Nginx rewrite without 301 code

Tags: curl, url-rewriting, nginx

I want to redirect all queries to my site to https protocol.
My config is:

```
    server {
    listen  80;
    server_name addons.vkzvuk.ru;
    server_name www.vkzvuk.ru;
    server_name vkzvuk.ru;
    rewrite ^ https://vkzvuk.ru$request_uri? permanent; }
```

When I make curl request **curl vkzvuk.ru** it returns html:

```
<h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1>
```

So, a lot of internet services can't show me google pr for example.

On the other hand, "curling" twitter and facebook returns empty result. How I can tune nginx to get the same behavior?

Comment: try to change "permanent" by "break"  cf http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

Answer (score 0):

Do not rewrite in the first place.

```
server {
    #listen 80 is default
    server_name _;
    return [HTTP_STATUS_CODE] https://$server_name$request_uri?;
}
```

Replace the `[HTTP_STATUS_CODE]` with whatever status code you’d like to send. But a 301 redirect would be correct at this place and I’d go for it. If you use the `return`-method as shown above nginx shouldn’t return any content, only the HTTP headers.